# Angular js not displaying test

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am following a tutorial on Angular JS, however the test isn't rendering as it's suppose to on the page. It should render as `"Hello you"`, but it still appearing as `{{"hello " + "you"}}`. I am very new to angular and any help would be appreciated.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js" ></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" > </script>
            <p>{{"hello " + "you"}}</p>
     </body>
</html>
```

The app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('store',[]);
```

and my folder structure:

```
root: 
   app.js
   angular.min.js
   shop.html
```

Comment: You have some typos in your `<script>` tags. The attribute should be `src` instead of `scr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your script tags. You misspelled the `src` attribute.

Below should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like that there was a typo in the answer about the typo. Makes we me want to put a typo in teh comment.